# Get json array length and looping

Tags: android, json, arrays

So I have a json response from web service like this

```
{
    error: false
    types: [2]
    -0:  {
        card_type_id: 5
        category: "Food & Beverages"
    }
    -1:  {
        card_type_id: 8
        category: "Entertaiment"
    }
}
```

what I want to do is to get the number inside json array "types" and use it to looping to set the value of arraylist that will be use in listview, but my code seems and cannot get the json array length, this is my code

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
if(!obj.getBoolean("error")){
    JSONArray types = obj.getJSONArray("types");
    for(int i=0; i<types.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject a = types.getJSONObject(i);
        int ct_id = a.getInt("card_type_id");
        String category = a.getString("category");

        CardType ct = new CardType();
        ct.setTypeId(_ct_id);
        ct.setTypeCategory(_category);

        categoryArray.add(ct);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks before

Comment: For starters, your JSON string is invalid. Secondly, types.length() in this case is 1, whereas I suspect you're counting on it to be 2. It's not perfectly clear what you're after but in case I'm on the right track, I'll post an answer with a proper JSON response.

Comment: @mjp66 thanks before for your fast reply, it's actually a json response from web service, and what do you mean by invalid? Can you give me an answer with a proper JSON response? sorry for my english

Comment: Posted an answer with an example of a correct response. As for your web service, you're going to have to look into that and figure out why the response you get is badly formatted.

Comment: @mjp66 thank you sir, i will immediately post an correct answer after i found the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your JSON response probably should look like (note also that keys and string values should be sorrounded by double-quotes):

```
{
    "error": false,
    "types": [
        {
            "card_type_id": 5,
            "category": "Food & Beverages"
        },
        {
            "card_type_id": 8,
            "category": "Entertaiment"
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSONArray "types" in this example has a length (types.length()) of 2. Now you can implement your for-loop and should get the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

actually it's just my fault to see the json from advanced rest client, i use the json menu and the app automatically correct the json and become invalid, after i change to raw menu i can see the actual json and correct the code